# Output not showing while doing binary search in c programming

Tags: c

I am a beginner c programmer. I was implementing Binary search in c programming. It seems to compile without any errors. But the problem is it is not showing any output. I cant understand what is the problem .Could anyone tell me what all changes should I make In this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*initializing the function. It takes three parameters. name of the 
  array, size of the array 
   and the number you want to find*/   

int binary_search(int arr[] , int size , int number);


int main(){

// creating an array
int arr[] = {2,34,45,56,67,78,89,90};

//defining the size
int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);

// calling the function
binary_search(arr,size,45);
}

// defining the function
int binary_search(int arr[],int size , int number){

    int start = 0;

    int end = size-1;

    while(start<end){
        int mid = (start+end)/2;
        // checking if the mid number is the number i am searching
        if(arr[mid]==number){
            printf("%d",arr[mid]);
            return 0;
        }

        else if(arr[mid]<number){
            start = mid+1;
        }

        else if(arr[mid]>number){
            end = mid-1;
        }

    // if start is not less than end
    else{
        return -1;
    }
 }
}
```

Why is it not showing any output. What all changes should I make in this code. Please reply.

Comment: What do you expect this program to output ? You are not using return value nor printing anything

Comment: `start = arr[0]`? You want an index here, so `start = 0`. And you should recalculate the middle index for each iteration, not once before the loop.

Comment: First you should decide what your function returns -- is is just a boolean that tells whether the number is in the array or is it a position plus a special value, say −1, for "not found"? (You should return a valid result for all code paths. Enable warnings.) Then you can do something with that result, for example print it.

Comment: I edited the code. I am printing the mid value if the number i am searching for and the mid value is same. Now also it is not showing any output.

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run the program in a debugger and trace it as it runs. Or at least add in more debug print statements to print for example the start, mid and end for each iteration. Then you may see that `while(start<end)` is not totally correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is because for first iteration `mid=3` (i.e value `arr[3]=56`).
so it will reduce the end and will be `end=3-1=2` (i.e value `arr[2]=45`) .
but you have not checked `arr [end]` after reduction due to which it got skipped.similarly it will also cause similar problem when your `start` will increase so kindly mention these checking it in your `if statement`.

try this:

```
if(arr[mid]==number||arr[end]==number ||arr[start]==number){
            printf("%d", number);
            return 0;
        }
```

OR,

Above code will return only element if found in array.Another option is to modify `while(start<end)` into `while(start<=end)` which will also check end element which was skipped previously.
And to print whether element is not in array just print it in `else` statement before `return -1`

Comment: I think you are on the right track. But the answer would be better if you described exactly what changes to the code are needed to fix the problem.

Comment: I tried by replacing your code with mine. It is also not working. It is just returning the number which i want to search. In here it is return 45. If i want to search 34 it is just return 34. Nothing else

Comment: @NAVANEETHJNAIR I've modified check it. It will return index of found element.

Comment: Yes it is working for me. Thank U